# ¿Cuál es el significado de USP?

Tags: sql

Quisiera conocer el significado de la abreviatura **USP** hablando del lenguaje SQL, tengo entendido que *SP* es: *Stored Procedure*, pero me queda la duda con la *U*, pienso que puede ser *User Stored Procedure*.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lee [ask]: el título de tu pregunta debe reflejar el contenido de la misma. _Duda con..._ no es un título que dé pistas a los demás.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es correcto. USP se usa para referirse a los Procedimientos Almacenados de Usuario y es para diferenciarlos de los Procedimientos Almacenados del Sistema. También existe la confusión en SQL Server (no sé en otros sistemas) con el prefijo SP, el cual se utiliza para objetos especiales que pueden o no ser Procedimientos Almacenados.